# Android - listFiles() doesn't list some files

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin

I'd like to make an Android app to list files and their size, a bit like WinDirStat or TreeSize on Windows, or DiskUsage on Android.

I tried this to get a list of files :

```
for (file in File("/sdcard").listFiles()) {
    println(file)
}
```

But it gives only the directories

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Expected output       | Output                |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Alarms                | DCIM                  |
| Android               | Pictures              |
| Audiobooks            | ZEPETO                |
| Aurora                | Audiobooks            |
| DCIM                  | Solid Color Wallpaper |
| Documents             | Snapchat              |
| Download              | Aurora                |
| EnergizedProtection   | aria2                 |
| Movies                | Ringtones             |
| Music                 | TWRP                  |
| Notifications         | Documents             |
| Pictures              | Music                 |
| Podcasts              | Telegram              |
| Ringtones             | Notifications         |
| Snapchat              | WhatsApp              |
| Snapseed              | Download              |
| Solid Color Wallpaper | Movies                |
| TWRP                  | Android               |
| Telegram              | EnergizedProtection   |
| WhatsApp              | Snapseed              |
| ZEPETO                | Podcasts              |
| aria2                 | Alarms                |
| out.txt               |                       |
| thisisafile.txt       |                       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

I have the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` and the one for Android 10

EDIT :

I tested with file.walk, according to djacobsen13, and it too doesn't list `out.txt` nor `thisisafile.txt`. But it lists other .txt files (deeply in the cache or Android folders), so I conclude it's not about directories or not, but just not listing some files for strange reasons

EDIT 2 :

As blackapps said there's no description of the problem I add it here, I want to list all the files of the folder ("/sdcard" here or any other folder in it), but it returns only the folders and not the files

I put the app on GitHub : https://github.com/victorbnl/andirstat

EDIT 3 :

It lists all the files on Android 9

Comment: Ok. But what is the Android version of the used device?

Comment: `out.txt               |                       |
| thisisafile.txt` Those look pretty much like files.

Comment: `println(file)` That will not print file size. No.

Comment: Yes these are files, but these are of the EXPECTED output! And I don't want their size yet, only to list the files correctly. But thanks for you answer!

Comment: And the version is Android 10, sorry I forgot that

Comment: Well what is the problem as you got the expected output? You have no problem description in your post at all.

Comment: It's Android 11, sorry I forgot that I updated recently, but anyway I added the description in my post

Comment: `but it returns only the folders and not the files` How can you say so? It returns also two files. Everybody can see that.

Comment: The left column is the output I WANT, NOT the output I HAVE. The one at the right is the one I HAVE

Comment: And you are testing on an Android 11 device? Then who put those two files there? Your app cannot put files there. Well not normally.

Comment: I put those files here, using Termux (`echo a > thisisafile.txt` and `ls > out.txt`)

Comment: On Android 11 an app can only list its own files. The files it created itself. The owner of the file is important. Moteover your app cannot even create files on root of external storage. Try first.

Comment: But does that mean that file manager after A11 will completely stop existing??

Comment: Why do you think so?

Comment: If there's no way to access files not created by the app, it means that file managers can't exist, doesn't it?

Comment: Normally an app can not. But you can request all files access. And if you got it you can.

Comment: Aaah ok I understand, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Try using this logic to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
File("${Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()}").walk().forEach {
      println(it)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, that's a very good idea! As I added in the main post, these don't list the files neither, I think it's because of Android 11

Answer (score 1):

I set the minimum SDK to 28 so that I use the permissions system from Android Pie, which is easier. I'm going to use this, at least as a temporary solution, before the Android 11 system is more documented

Answer (score 1):

Android 11 has added new permission settings: "Access to all files "

> [Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings#ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION)

Special permissions: You need to apply dynamically in the code, and request in the form of skipping system activities

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R && !Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
   // Access to all files
   val uri: Uri = Uri.parse("package:" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)
   val intent = Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION, uri)
   requireContext().startActivity(intent)
}
```

Works fine in my code.

Comment: Doesn't work in mine. Shows png but won't show .json, .docx, .txt.
They've really screwed up the OS with this stupid new system that nobody asked for!

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion to go inside the directories and fetch all files from there.

Comment: Same as djacoben13, it doesn't list these files neither